# error: ld-2.27.so in swift on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, glibc

I installed swift on my ubuntu 18.04 and when i start i get this error. but the code works fine when i'm writing them, I search some solution to fix this error but the thing is that i will remove the `libc6-dbg`. is it okay to remove this, and my other works wont effect after i deleted this? or should I ignore the swift error `ld-2.27.so` since my code working.

```
error: ld-2.27.so 0xffffffff0005c564: adding range [0x1464a-0x146ba) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x14dc0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.27.so 0xffffffff0005c564: adding range [0x146d0-0x146d6) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x14dc0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.27.so 0xffffffff0005c5c5: adding range [0x1464a-0x146ba) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x14dc0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.27.so 0xffffffff0005c5c5: adding range [0x146d0-0x146d6) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x14dc0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
Welcome to Swift version 5.0.2 (swift-5.0.2-RELEASE).
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8690

A workaround if you are not doing any debugging in glibc is to remove the debug version:

```
  sudo apt remove libc6-dbg
```